# adding cols to an 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am reading multiple .csv files in one by one, taking one column and accumulating these columns in an array and finally want to make a .csv file out of it.

```
enter code here
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os, os.path
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('C:\\Users\\me\\Desktop\\csvfiles'):
  for f in files:
    fullpath = os.path.join(root, f)
    if os.path.splitext(fullpath)[1] == '.csv':
       data = np.genfromtxt(fullpath, delimiter=',',names=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
       col_sel = np.array(data['B'])
       col_sel = np.hstack([col_sel])
    np.savetxt('test.csv', col_sel, delimiter=',')
```

Somehow this is not adding data to the array columnwise. everything else might fall in place if this works. Can someone tell me why?

Comment: you always get the second column and then stack it to itself , itmeans each time you overwrite it. You have to define another array beside than `col_sel` and stack  `col_sel` to it.

Comment: Dalek can you pls write a line of code which can do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stack them vertically and write them in a 2D array, at the end the number of columns is equal to the `CVS` files:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os, os.path
n=0
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('/users/test'):
  for f in files:
    fullpath = os.path.join(root, f)
    if os.path.splitext(fullpath)[1] == '.csv':
       data = np.genfromtxt(fullpath, delimiter=',',names=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
       if(n==0):
          col_sel = data['B']
       else:
          col_sel = np.vstack((col_sel,data['B']))
       n+=1
np.savetxt('/users/test.csv', col_sel, delimiter=',')
```

Comment: Thanks much. Appreciate it a lot. I works I tested it out. Used reshape to make rows into columns.